# angular jointJs html template

Tags: html, angularjs, templates, jointjs

I try to replace the html template into an angular directive to use a custom JointJS graph as html and not a regular JointJS objects. The following code is an example i found on the web which works great under JS and jQ, but when I try to replace that to an angular directive it doesnt render the code or worse, it duplicates the html table (when i run addCell func) but not drawing the table elm on the Graph. It also looks like the css rules are not being rendered to provide the new styles. 
Any ideas pls ?

```
//an example for creating JoinJS obj with HTML template
joint.shapes.html = {};
joint.shapes.html.Element = joint.shapes.basic.Rect.extend({
    defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
        type: 'html.Element',
        attrs: {
            rect: { stroke: 'none', 'fill-opacity': 0 }
        }
    }, joint.shapes.basic.Rect.prototype.defaults)
});

// Create a custom view for that element that displays an HTML div above it.
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
joint.shapes.html.ElementView = joint.dia.ElementView.extend({

    template: [
        // trying to convert the TABLE elem below to an angular directive
        //'<container-data></container-data>'

        '<table class="html-element"><tr><td><form onsubmit="return false;" action="">',
            '<button class="delete">x</button>',
            '<label></label>',
            '<i class="link_add" title="Add a link">L</i>',
            '<div class="section_title">Properties <i class="fa fa-caret-down fRight"></i></div>'
         '</form></td></tr></table>'

    ].join(''),
   // some funcs come here
});
$scope.loadBalancer = new joint.shapes.html.Element({position: { x: 20, y: 20 }, size: { height: 30 }, label: 'LoadBalancer', select: 'one' });

$scope.graph.addCells([$scope.loadBalancer]);
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I guess you need to use inline css while extending html element